# comparing image from ui to saved image in SQL server database Asp.net, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, image

I had developed an application in Asp.Net which saves image in SQL Server database it fines, but i want a scenario like this When i am trying to save same image again then it should gives me message that the image is duplicate. How to do this? How we can compare a image from UI & SQL database in Asp.net?

please help me friends
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the image is **exactly** the same, then you could make a hash of the image object which is saved in a separate column, and check if there are any columns that matches any entries in that column whenever you try to save an image.

If you need to check if the image is similar or just looks the same, then you need more advanced image recognition software..